# How to copy a value down a column with the same ID? Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

[image]

Ideally I would like to do this within ADF. Is this possible to do within ADF?

Alternatively, can this be done in Azure SQL Database?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach to [Implement Fill Down in ADF and Synapse Data Flows](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/implement-fill-down-in-adf-and-synapse-data-flows/ba-p/2013406)

and if in SQL, you can use as below where `invoice` is the table name

[image]

```
DECLARE @v nvarchar(max);

UPDATE invoice WITH(TABLOCKX)
SET @v = Invoice_Number = CASE WHEN Invoice_Number IS NULL THEN @v ELSE Invoice_Number END
OPTION(MAXDOP 1);

DECLARE @vd nvarchar(max);

UPDATE invoice WITH(TABLOCKX)
SET @vd = Invoice_Date = CASE WHEN Invoice_Date IS NULL THEN @vd ELSE Invoice_Date END
OPTION(MAXDOP 1);

 
SELECT * FROM invoice;
```

[image]